# javascript function call after process execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, overlay, show

I am facing issue regarding javascript.
Onclick of button a call a function

```
function onButtonClickFunction()
{
    ajaxCall();
}

function ajaxCall()
{
    $('.black_overlay').show();

    /* Some Ajax Code */

    $('.black_overlay').hide();
}
```

So here I am facing the issue is, When I call the ajaxCall function, ideally overlay should be appear, But this will appear and hide at the end of the Ajax response.

There is no error in the console. And when check with the breakpoints then this function sequentially works.

I really didn't come to know, where should be the problem. What should I check for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a callback to hide the element

Comment: Problem is not with the hiding. Problem is with the appearing overlay. I want to appear overlay as the ajaxCall function called, but it appears, after Ajax response

Answer (score 0):

You should use your code to hide overlay inside ajax.success or ajax.error, because ajax runs async.

Thats why your overlay hides faster than request finishes

Comment: Thanks for you response, But here the problem is overlay doesn't show when function is called, the screen is looking unresponsive, between request and response.

Comment: @user3483449 then you should provide more code. Create a jsfiddle example, so we could run and test it - only then we will be able to help you

Comment: I have tried as separate application, it is working fine. but when I use like at button call, It works, but after when i got response.